# Добавление данных с толбец, через цикл

Tags: python, pandas

Имеется 3 столбика. Нужно сравнить COL1 и COL2, найти одинаковый результат. После сравнения записать результат в COL3.

Файл изначальный.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге файл должен получиться таким.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
import pandas as pd

test1 = pd.read_excel('test1.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1', usecols=['COL1', 'COL2', 'COL3'])

for i in test1['COL1']:
    for j in test1['COL2']:
        if(i == j):
            print(j)
```

По логике данные сравнил правильно, на выходе выводятся числа 1-11. Но как записать результат в третий столбик COL3 не понимаю.

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: и сформулируйте понятно вопрос. Как понимать "то что есть в обоих столбцах записать в COL3"?

Comment: условие не понятно все равно. если i==j, то что должно быть в итоге? а если не равно, то что?

Comment: А попробуйте самостоятельно понять, как по фразе "После сравнения записать РЕЗКЛЬТАТ в COL3" и картинке желаемого результата, в которой содержимое колонки  COL3 полностью повторяет содержимое  СOL1,  понять, что же вы хотели сказать.  А также по фразе  "Нужно сравнить COL1 и COL2, найти одинаковый результат" понять, что такое ОДИНАКОВЫЙ результат построчного сравнения?  Про то, как этот результат сравнения согласуется с картинкой желаемого результата -  вообще даже страшно спрашивать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял вопрос:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2,3], "b":[2,3,4]})

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
   a  b
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  3  4

In [3]: np.intersect1d(df["a"], df["b"])
Out[3]: array([2, 3])

In [4]: isect = np.intersect1d(df["a"], df["b"])

In [5]: df.loc[df["a"].isin(isect), "res"] = df["a"]

In [6]: df
Out[6]:
   a  b  res
0  1  2  NaN
1  2  3  2.0
2  3  4  3.0
```

Comment: Спасибо, то что нужно.